# Eclipse wont run: \.metadata\.log error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I was working on an Android project and after restarting the computer, eclipse won't run. 
It's throwing the .metadata.log file error.

Comment: Can you be more descriptive on the error thrown?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try using a new workspace. To force the workspace window prompt you need to change the settings in `<Eclipse_root_dir>\configuration\.settings\org.eclipse.ui.ide.prefs` and set `SHOW_WORKSPACE_SELECTION_DIALOG` to `true`.

Source: [Eclipse Community Forums](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/156204/)

Answer (score 17):

Go to `~\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources`
You will find **.snap** file. Just delete it.
Relaunch Eclipse.

It will work perfectly.

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to delete your .metadata folder because in this way it's going to delete your preferences about your workspace. However delete snap files that exist inside your .metadata folder as well as the .lock files.

Also after you do this don't forget to do a clean start of eclipe

```
./eclipse -clean
```

Answer (score 3):

I have also some issues while running Eclipse (with Mercurial and Aptana Plugins).

If you want to find out what is causing this problem backup `.metadata` folder and "incrementally" delete folders in `<your_workspace_folder>/.metadata/plugins/`. If you delete some folder and Eclipse will run you'll knew that this is the problem.

For Mercurial I delete `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\snap`
and for Aptana `workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.core.resources\.safetable`

If you don't care if your preferences get lost simply delete `.metadata` folder and run Eclipse again - it'll create new `.metadata` folder.

Answer (score 3):

You can do a binary search in this folder (each time use a different subset of plugins) to find which folder causes the problems.

For me, deleting the folder "...\workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench" fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Just delete ~ **WorkSapce \ .metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.e4.workbench**  folder . Then relaunch the Eclipse. It works for me.

Comment: Thank you! This was the only thing that worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. I deleted /.metadata but I could not solve this problem. If you are installing Eclipse with Java 9, you may not be able to solve this problem by just deleting .metadata or log folders.

Here is what I did. I extracted and install eclipse in /opt/eclipse on Ubuntu 16.04. My java version was 9 and Eclipse version was oxygen 4.7.0.

I added "--add-modules=ALL-SYSTEM" at the last line of my eclipse.ini file. Then, I solved this problem. Since the Eclipse SDK uses that aren't in the java.base modeul, I needed to add this line in eclipse.ini file. See this URL: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Configure_Eclipse_for_Java_9. I hope this help to others. It was easy to fix but it took me for while to find this solution.

Answer (score 1):

This link solved my issue: https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#-vm_value:_Mac_OS_X_Example. I followed the Mac Example. I located the file eclipse.ini. I then selected "Get info" and change ".ini" to ".txt". This allowed me to edit the text in the file. I then went to finder, went to Macintosh HD -> Library -> Java -> JavaVirtualMachines -> jdk1.8.0_144.jdk -> Contents -> Home -> bin. Then I opened the eclipse.txt file with the general Text Editor. This is the path I then copied into the text file eclipse.txt right under "-vm" like this "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_144.jdk/Contents/Home/bin". I then hit command save. Then I selected "Get info" on the eclipse.txt file and changed the ".txt" to ".ini" and replied yes I'm sure to use ".ini" when a little pop up box came. Then I exited out of finder and relaunched eclipse with success!

Answer (score 0):

For those who have the .metadata/.log error, just install the java jdk-8u144 and its done.

Answer (score 0):

None of this worked for me, I used java 8.221 and Eclipse Oxygen. So I tried this.
I edited `eclipse.ini` and before `-vmargs` put

```
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\bin\javaw.exe
```

And it started working

Src: https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1089060/

Answer (score -1):

Navigate to android-sdks (mine is at C:\Users\azeuner\android-sdks\platform-tools) then click on platform-tools, then click on adb.exe this will refresh eclipse. It worked for me !