# Eclipse cannot find .metadata/.log

Tags: java, android, eclipse, crash

Eclipse crashes on startup. It issues a message informing me that the *.metadata/.log* files could not be found. In order to resolve this issue:

- I have tried changing the workspace to another existing workspace and
  to a new folder.
- I have tried removing the .lock files within the .metadata/.log
  folder.
- I have also tried removing the entire metadata folder.

What should I do in order to solve this problem?

Comment: .metadata/.log shouldn't be a *folder*, it's a file.

Comment: Try to delete that workspace and again create same workspace.

Comment: Check out the similar posts http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11810102/eclipse-juno-startup-error-log-file Also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939822/eclipse-wont-run-metadata-log-error which might help you.

Comment: What is the exact message you get?

Answer (score 0):

Create New Workspace . .metadata file Contains the information about  all the project, currently in the workspace . 
In  your case .metadata   may be corrupted or deleted 
so Create New workspace