# No version of Eclipse will start after installing Oxygen

Tags: eclipse

After trying to install the oxygen IDE, Eclipse has simply stopped working altogether. I had the Neon binaries in one folder and decided to install Oxygen in another directory. Now neither program will start! I am using Linux Mint.

I have checked

[Eclipse wont run: \.metadata\.log error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939822/eclipse-wont-run-metadata-log-error)

but it doesn't apply to my situation; changing the workspace doesn't solve my problem.

I am simply given the message "An error has occurred. See the log file" and that is all.

The content of the log file can be found here:

https://pastebin.com/mMprapQ8

Basically, it repeats messages of the form

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.annotation.PostConstruct cannot be found by org.eclipse.e4.core.di_1.6.1.v20160712-0927
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:486)
```

I have tried reinstalling Java, but this doesn't help either.

Comment: With ubuntu,same problem here,have you solved this problem?